# Are the notes in Blues scale in Am I Evil solo?

Tags: guitar, scales, modes, solos, metal

```
e|-11-12-11---11-12-14-14-14-12-11-12-11----|-----------------7---|

B|---------12----------------------------12-|-10---------/7-------|
```

I am analyzing the Guitar Solo of Metallica's cover version of Diamond Head's song, "Am I Evil". I have trouble understanding these notes shown above.
The solo is played over a B power chord and Kirk starts playing the Blues scale, I believe, starting at F# by bending the G string on Fret 9 (E). In the next measure he starts playing the D# on the Low E string on 11th fret then plays the E note immediately after.

But D# is not in the Blues scale of B, or in the Dorian scale. But it still sounds right, musical to my ears. How is it possible these notes are not in one scale? Or is it another scale?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117558/discussion-on-question-by-abel-tom-are-the-notes-in-blues-scale-in-am-i-evil-sol). - and a reminder, please be polite and patient. People ask these questions because they don't know yet.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem I am really sorry if I came across as impolite and impatient, that was not my intention.

Comment: Hi Abel - don’t worry, the comment was not aimed at you :-)